# How do I query sub document when using $lookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here's my problem: I am trying to query subdocument `bulk` by it's property name. I can't find any operator to do that.

I have tried using `$match` like this - `$match: { 'bulk.name': 'xyz' }` but it doesn't work.

```
const query = [
    {
        $match: { user },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { bulk: '$bulk', status: '$status' },
            count: { $sum: 1 },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id.bulk',
            status: { $addToSet: { status: '$_id.status', count: '$count' } },
        },
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'bulks',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'bulk',
        },
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [{ $arrayElemAt: ['$bulk', 0] }, '$$ROOT'] } },
    },
    { $project: { bulk: 0 } },
]
```

sample data

```
items:
    [{
        _id: 6040 d71f40f98b3e3cc518c9,
        type: 'Gateway',
        name: 'Lite Bulk Group Ultra FE Dupe__3/4/2021, 12:36:38 PM',
        description: '',
        message: '{{name}} {{Message-optional}} {{another-one}} {{another-two}}',
        group: 6017 b457f5105418b8099ab6,
        user: 5 fc871135fd04f562aed3527,
        schedule: 6040 d71f40f98b3e3cc518c2,
        createdAt: 2021 - 03 - 04 T12: 48: 31.661 Z,
        updatedAt: 2021 - 03 - 04 T12: 48: 31.661 Z,
        __v: 0,
        status: [Array]
    }]
```

Comment: please add sample data

Comment: items: [
    {
      _id: 6040d71f40f98b3e3cc518c9,
      type: 'Gateway',
      name: 'Lite Bulk Group Ultra FE Dupe__3/4/2021, 12:36:38 PM',
      description: '',
      message: '{{name}} {{Message-optional}} {{another-one}} {{another-two}}',
      group: 6017b457f5105418b8099ab6,
      user: 5fc871135fd04f562aed3527,
      schedule: 6040d71f40f98b3e3cc518c2,
      createdAt: 2021-03-04T12:48:31.661Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-03-04T12:48:31.661Z,
      __v: 0,
      status: [Array]
    },
  ],

Comment: add your data and query here  and update the story https://mongoplayground.net/